# Getting an error message while trying to build Play Scala project in Intellij Idea Ultimate version 14.0.4

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

While creating Scala play project via Intellij Idea ultimate version 14.0.4 I'm facing with error which is below. I'have tried all alternatives to solve this problem like updating the plugin, building project in command prompt and importing it to Idea etc, but nothing helped me. Even tried some advices from stackoverflow also did not help. So any other way that might help to solve this problem?

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: sbt-run-support-210#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
Invalid response.
Invalid response.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0

See complete log in C:\Users\admins\.IntelliJIdea14\system\log\sbt.last.log
```

Answer (score 0):

`sbt` seems to be unable to resolve `sbt-run-support-210#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

`sbt-run-support` looks like a sbt plugin.

The first step would be to check the log for the unresolved dependency. So please add the content of `C:\Users\admins.IntelliJIdea14\system\log\sbt.last.log` to your question.

From here on, I'm just guessing:

You will probably find something along the lines of:

```
[warn]  module not found: ???#sbt-run-support;0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:/Users/admins.IntelliJIDea14/.ivy2/local/???/sbt-run-support/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots/***/sbt-run-support/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/???/sbt-run-support_2.10_0.13/0.1-SNAPSHOT/sbt-run-support-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: ???#sbt-run-support;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
```

Some time ago many repositories were moved to `bintray.com` and the JCenter repository.

So I found your module [here](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.typesafe.play%3Asbt-run-support_2.10/view).

And thus, a possible fix could be to either add download *sbt-launcher* version 0.13.6+ and configure Idea to use this sbt-launcher to build projects. Because since version 0.13.6 *SBT* has the proper resolvers build in. Then you might still have to add a new resolver to your build.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo
```

Comment: I did not get you, please explain with simple words I'm not good in English. Thanks!